# Error trying to run my .Net Core MVC Project. What can I do?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to run my  .Net Core MVC project in Visual Studio 2019, but when I try it, I get that message: "unable to install asp.net core development certificate tool"

I found this command here in stackoverflow **dotnet dev-certs https --trust** for solve that problem, but when a try to run this or another command in the console using the **dotnet** command I get this error.

````
dotnet run
Fatal error. Failed to load JIT compiler
   at System.SpanHelpers.IndexOf(Char ByRef, Char, Int32)
   at System.String.Ctor(Char*)
   at System.AppContext.Setup(Char**, Char**, Int32)```
````

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? Can you please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) It's possible this is an issue with corruption of your .NET installation. If you have that example and others can reproduce it, it's in your app. If others can't reproduce it, you may need to clean or reinstall the SDK / Runtime.

Comment: I have reinstalled the Runtime and .Net Core SDK and now all is ok. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

I have reinstalled the Runtime and .Net Core SDK from the Visual Studio Installer, and installed the .Net Core SDK package directly from the .exe installer,  and now all is ok.